# How to include Glue 4.x libraries in my app? - not having any luck finding out where these jars live

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, dependencies, aws-glue

I'm trying to upgrade form Glue 2.x to 4.x and have succesfully gotten to 3.x.
Glue 4.x is more of a headache because i can't find any examples of how to configure a build
(any example would help: sbt/maven/gradle) that pulls that particular dependency.

There are tons of examples on github that illustrate how to pull Glue 3.x... For example:

```
https://github.com/novakov-alexey-zz/spark-elt-jobs/blob/138c1c479d7f68b8fcafbb7daca5889fe2944f18/project/Dependencies.scala
```

I thought i could move up if i just bumped the version like this:

```
lazy val awsGlue = "com.amazonaws" % "AWSGlueETL" % "3.0.0" ->
lazy val awsGlue = "com.amazonaws" % "AWSGlueETL" % "4.0.0"
```

But I get this error building from sbt>
not found: https://aws-glue-etl-artifacts.s3.amazonaws.com/release/com/amazonaws/AWSGlueETL/4.0.0/AWSGlueETL-4.0.0.pom

4.0.0 version of the .jar doesn't seem to be there.

I can execute the command below and pull jar for 3.0.0  ->
wget https://aws-glue-etl-artifacts.s3.amazonaws.com/release/com/amazonaws/AWSGlueETL/3.0.0/AWSGlueETL-3.0.0.jar

But when i try the same thing for 4.0.0 it fails
wget https://aws-glue-etl-artifacts.s3.amazonaws.com/release/com/amazonaws/AWSGlueETL/4.0.0/AWSGlueETL-4.0.0.jar

Any guidance much appreciated !

Comment: Now `wget https://aws-glue-etl-artifacts.s3.amazonaws.com/release/com/amazonaws/AWSGlueETL/4.0.0/AWSGlueETL-4.0.0.jar` is working.

Comment: awesome. thnx !

Answer (score 0):

OK.. so AWS support tells me there is no .jar available yet. They verified w/ the exact same wget command i used above. Why do they do a release w/o this important capability of doing a scala/java build which depends on this new .jar?   You can only use Glue from their console now.  Hope they fix.. but this is the situation now.